# Who is the highest rep user that has earned the tumbleweed badge?

Tags: discussion, tumbleweed-badge

I was looking through some of the highest rep users' profiles and noticed none of them had earned the tumbleweed badge. I can think of several reasons why, but which user who earned that badge, currently, has the most rep?

Comment: I would think that high-rep users would be _more_ likely to earn Tumbleweed. When you're the best person on SO, and you have a question, who's going to be able to answer it?

Comment: @Pops but such questions will also get votes won't they? Super-hard questions by SO legends definitely get super-high upvotes too right?

Comment: @Unitato You're right! I just took a quick glance at the top few all-time SO users, and they've mostly asked a decent number of questions (though far less than they've answered). Almost all are high-scoring and answered, so, so much for my seven-year-old prediction. New thoughts: just because you know a lot about a lot of things doesn't mean there aren't specific fields where your expertise is low; in other words, high overall rep doesn't make you "the best person on SO" for _every_ topic. Also, high rep probably correlates with knowing how to effectively ask a question/communicate generally.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a query using the [data dump](http://odata.stackexchange.com) which would be data up to the first of the month:

```
SELECT TOP 10 u.DisplayName, u.Reputation 
FROM Badges b
INNER JOIN Users u ON b.UserId = u.Id
WHERE b.Name='Tumbleweed'
ORDER By u.Reputation DESC​
```

The top 10 results:

```
DisplayName               Reputation 
------------------------- ---------- 
tvanfosson                121740     
paxdiablo                 106246     
Darin Dimitrov            102569     
marc_s                    84944      
SLaks                     80588      
Pekka                     71504      
Bill Karwin               66385      
Bozho                     57980      
skaffman                  55425      
Remus Rusanu              54865
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed that one. The question that awarded the user the badge was a good but obscure question.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a data dump query: http://odata.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/591/users-with-the-tumbleweed-badge-ordered-by-reputation

```
select top 10 * from badges b join users u on b.userid = u.id
where b.Name = 'Tumbleweed'
order by u.Reputation desc
```

Of course, the data dump is missing some data, so it cannot tell you which question got the badge, or how much reputation the user had when s/he got it.